# Prevent showing system context menu on right click on Form title bar

Tags: c#, .net, forms, winforms

How can I disable right click on title bar of the form and prevent showing system context menu:

[image]

Help me to get out of this issue

thank you

Comment: winforms = winapi, you could [process windows messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.message) and prevent certain to reach `base.WndProc()`. Not sure how exactly though.

Comment: @moathnaji In fact the suggested duplicate has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Sorry its seems to me that same functionality !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you specifically want to disable showing system context menu on right click on window's title bar, you can handle [`WM_CONTEXTMENU`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-contextmenu?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235):

```
const int WM_CONTEXTMENU = 0x007B;
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == WM_CONTEXTMENU)
        m.Result = IntPtr.Zero;
    else
        base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

If you also want to prevent the possibility of clicking on form's icon to show the context menu, then you can set [`ShowIcon`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showicon?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) property of the form to `false`:

```
this.ShowIcon = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting your `Window Style` property to '`None`'? This should remove the Title Bar's Context Menu completely.

Comment: but I need title bar and want to disable right click. I Managed to stop double click now just need to stop right cliick

Comment: You'll need to use this code (or something similar) to capture the right mouse click. You'll want to use this in the MouseClick event of your title bar. [This link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7273/How-to-detect-a-left-mouse-click-on-a-Winform-titl) may help you. 
`if (e.Button.ToString().ToLower()=="right")`
`{`
 `//do whatever you need.`
`}`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by setting the `ControlBox` property of form to `false`.

```
public Form1()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     this.ControlBox = false;
}
```

No more Context Menu with Restore, Maximize Minimize, Close, Move will be displayed on Right Clicking on the Title Bar.

```
this.ControlBox = false;
```

Note: Above one line (`this.ControlBox = false;`), is the key and the Form1 Constructor with InitializeComponent() method call is shown is the sample, just to show the context.